# How can I create order numbers based on the values of another column?

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm trying to create a order number (1,2,3...etc), based on the values of the dateAndCheckNumber column. Each unique dateAndCheckNumber should have its own order number. The code below works, but it takes a long time because it's a for loop. I need to recreate this process with a much larger dataset, and I'm looking for something that runs more efficiently. I tried using `mutate` with the `dplyr` package, but I couldn't figure out how to get a counter to work.

```
dataset <- dataset[order(dataset$dateAndCheckNumber),]
for(i in 1:nrow(dataset)){
if(i==1){
  dataset$orderNumber[1] <-1
  count <- 1
}
else{
  if(dataset$dateAndCheckNumber[i]==(dataset$dateAndCheckNumber)[i-1]){
    dataset$dateAndCheckNumber[i] <- count
  } else {
    count <- count+1
    dataset$dateAndCheckNumber[i] <- count
  }
}
```

}

Comment: The `data.table` solution should work fine. But if you are looking for a solution with `dplyr`, look into `group_indices`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In base R, probably the easiest and fastest way to accomplish this is by means of `as.integer(as.factor())`.

Here is an example with the data from the answer by @dayne:

```
set.seed(1234)
id <- sample(LETTERS[1:6],6,replace=TRUE)
df1 <- data.frame(id, counter=as.integer(as.factor(id)))
#> df1
#  id counter
#1  A       1
#2  D       2
#3  D       2
#4  D       2
#5  F       3
#6  D       2
```

Comment: @Bschrein Glad to hear that. Please consider accepting the answer that you found most helpful by [clicking on the tick at the left.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234)

Answer (score 0):

Using the data.table package, you can create a column with the unique group number using the `.GRP` variable:

```
library(data.table)
set.seed(1234)
DT <- data.table(id = sample(LETTERS[1:6], 6, replace = TRUE))
DT[ , counter := .GRP, by = id]
DT
#    id counter
# 1:  A       1
# 2:  D       2
# 3:  D       2
# 4:  D       2
# 5:  F       3
# 6:  D       2
```

Comment: @RHertel Thanks for the shoutout. SO has been pretty frustrating lately, so I appreciate it!